# MySQL query take too long

Tags: mysql

MySQL server give no reply and hanged after the following query:

```
SELECT 
i.id AS id, 
i.name AS product, 
i.stock AS stock, 
IF(SUM(s1.qty) IS NULL, 0, SUM(s1.qty)) AS thisqty, 
IF(SUM(s2.qty) IS NULL, 0, SUM(s2.qty)) AS lastqty, 
IF(SUM(s3.qty) IS NULL, 0, SUM(s3.qty)) AS last2qty, 
IF(SUM(s4.qty) IS NULL, 0, SUM(s4.qty)) AS last3qty 
FROM 
item i, 
sale s1, sale s2, sale s3, sale s4, 
odr o1, odr o2, odr o3, odr o4 
WHERE 
i.id = s1.itemid AND s1.oui = o1.oui AND (o1.ddate BETWEEN '2016-02-08' AND '2016-02-14') AND 
i.id = s2.itemid AND s2.oui = o2.oui AND (o2.ddate BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-07') AND 
i.id = s3.itemid AND s3.oui = o3.oui AND (o3.ddate BETWEEN '2016-01-25' AND '2016-01-31') AND 
i.id = s4.itemid AND s4.oui = o4.oui AND (o4.ddate BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24') GROUP BY PRODUCT;
```

My table structure are as follows:

```
mysql> describe item;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(3)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| wprice  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sprice  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bprice  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| stock   | float        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| buyfrom | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| unit    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> describe odr;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| oui    | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| odate  | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ddate  | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| otime  | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cid    | varchar(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| disc   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| net    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> describe sale;

+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| oui    | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| itemid | varchar(3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty    | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| amount | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| profit | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

I tried query with s1 and it worked. May be too many ANDs in where clause. 
I also tried with phpmyadmin and still didnt work

Comment: do you have indexes on `itemid `,`oui` and `ddate`?

Comment: No, would that be a problem?

Comment: That the biggest problem. Create index an composite index for the fields and show the explain for your query

Comment: @Thomas Moe: Create indexes of columns to get performance in queries and have you tried the query which I just answered?

Answer (score 0):

Changed query to filter data inside the sub queries.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    i.id AS id, 
    i.name AS product, 
    i.stock AS stock, 
    IF(SUM(s1.qty) IS NULL, 0, SUM(s1.qty)) AS thisqty, 
    IF(SUM(s2.qty) IS NULL, 0, SUM(s2.qty)) AS lastqty, 
    IF(SUM(s3.qty) IS NULL, 0, SUM(s3.qty)) AS last2qty, 
    IF(SUM(s4.qty) IS NULL, 0, SUM(s4.qty)) AS last3qty 
FROM  item i
inner join (select sale.* from sale 
                inner join odr on sale.oui=odr.oui 
                where odr.ddate BETWEEN '2016-02-08' AND '2016-02-14'
            ) s1 on i.id = s1.itemid 
inner join (select sale.* from sale 
                inner join odr on sale.oui=odr.oui 
                where odr.ddate BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-07'
            ) s2 on i.id = s2.itemid 

inner join (select sale.* from sale 
                inner join odr on sale.oui=odr.oui 
                where odr.ddate BETWEEN '2016-01-25' AND '2016-01-31'
            ) s3 on i.id = s3.itemid 

inner join (select sale.* from sale 
                inner join odr on sale.oui=odr.oui 
                where odr.ddate BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24'
            ) s4 on i.id = s4.itemid             
GROUP BY PRODUCT;
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got this error: #1060 - Duplicate column name 'oui'

Comment: I added the indexes in the tabels

Comment: You are getting this error because I am selecting `oui` column from both `sale` and `odr` in Subquery. anyway check the updated answer.